# Proving injectivity of a certain polynomial function

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials, factoring

So I have to find the second derivative of the inverse function of:

$$f_{(x)}=3x^4+2x^3-8x^2-20x-160 ;  x\ge 2$$

which I already have done, but I still need to prove the function is injective over the given domain.

I've tried the classic $f_{(x_1)}=f_{(x_2)}~$, but I end up with a factor I'm unable to simplify by using elementary methods.

$$f_{(x_1)}=f_{(x_2)}~$$
$$3x_1^4+2x_1^3-8x_1^2-20x_1-160=3x_2^4+2x_2^3-8x_2^2-20x_2-160$$
$$3(x_1^4-x_2^4)+2(x_1^3-x_2^3)-8(x_1^2-x_2^2)-20(x_1-x_2)=0$$
$$3(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)+2(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)-8(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)-20(x_1-x_2)=0$$
$$(x_1-x_2)(3(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1+x_2)+2(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)-8(x_1+x_2)-20)=0$$

so I found the $(x_1-x_2)$ factor I needed, but I can't find a way to simplify or to factor the second expression, or a way to prove it can't be equal to 0 over the function's domain.

How would one do it? Or is another way of proving the function's injectivity, other than graphing, recommended? If someone could prove it and tell me the procedure they used, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `another way of proving the function's injectivity` Show that $f$ is strictly increasing for $x \ge 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x\geq2$ we obtain:
$$(3x^4+2x^3-8x^2-20x-160)'=2(6x^3+3x^2-8x-10)=$$
$$=2(6x^3-12x^2+15x^2-30x+22x-44+34)=$$
$$=2(x-2)(6x^2+15x+22)+68>0,$$ which gives which you want.

Answer (score 3):

One could also continue from
$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=
  (x_1-x_2)(3(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1+x_2)+2(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)-8(x_1+x_2)-20)=0$ at the end of the original question. The desired result $x_1=x_2$ would follows from
  $3(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1+x_2)+2(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)-8(x_1+x_2)-20
\not=0$  for $x_1,x_2\geq2$.
  Note that 
 $3(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1+x_2)-8(x_1+x_2)=
   (x_1+x_2)[3(x_1^2+x_2^2)-8]\geq 4\cdot 16=64$.
   Accordingly $3(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1+x_2)+2(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)-8(x_1+x_2)-20\geq64+24-20>0$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) = 12x^3+6x^2-16x-20 = x(12x^2+6x-16)-20$. Then $f'(2)=68>0$ and $x(12x^2+6x-16)>20$ for all $x \geq 2$ so $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \geq 2$. Then $f$ is strictly increasing over this domain, so it is injective.